# TypedFactory Disposes Before Component Using it As a Dependency

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have an interface and a typed factory interface:

```
public interface ITransientItem : IDisposable
{
    void DoWork(WorkItem item);
}

public interface ITransientItemFactory : IDisposable
{
    ITransientItem Create();
    void Destroy(ITransientItem item);
}
```

I Then have an implementation of another interface `IDependencyOwner : IDisposable`  which is implementend by:

```
public class DependencyOwner: IDependencyOwner
{
    private ITransientItemFactory _factory;

    public DependencyOwner(ITransientItemFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void PostWork(WorkItem workItem)
    {
        ITransientItem item = _factory.Create();

        item.DoWork(workItem); //this is done on a seperate thread

        _factory.Destroy(item);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //first wait for running items to dispose

       //then do disposal stuff
    }
}
```

The `DependencyOwner` is held a dependency for yet another object, and there can be many implementations of DependencyOwner, which are resolved with the `CollectionResolver` Sub Resolver. but I don't believe that it is relevant to this problem. Its Constructor looks like:

`public TopLevel(IDependencyOwner[] dependencies)`

Container Registration looks like this:

```
    WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.AddFacility(new TypedFactoryFacility());
    container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));

    container.Register(Component.For<TopLevel>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IDependencyOwner>().ImplementedBy<DependencyOwner>();
    //there will be more IDependencyOwner Implementations in the future

    container.Register(Component.For<ITransientItem>().ImplementedBy<TransientItem>()
        .LifeStyle.Transient);

    container.Register(Component.For<ITransientItemFactory>().AsFactory());

    TopLevel top = container.Resolve<TopLevel>();
```

Everything with the code actually running is fine. The problem comes when it is time to close the program.

The `ITransientItemFactory` is getting disposed before DependencyOwner's Dispose method is even called (I have verified this by putting a breakpoint on the very first line of the dispose method and then then checking my log to see that the error is already present). This causes any workItems that were in the middle of processing to fail, and the program crashes rather than ending gracefully.

The exception I get is:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: The factory was disposed and can no
>   longer be used. Object name: 'this'.

Why is Windsor not honoring this dependency?

EDIT: I stumbled on [this trick](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/02/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-8-dependency.html) here and have been able to confirm that the factory does appear in the dependency graph as a dependency of DependencyOwner.

EDIT 2: I have just implemented the factory myself and removed the typed factory. This solved my problem (As the dependency was honored), but I would rather not do this if I can avoid it. Just for illustrative purposes, the registration in this case becomes:

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    //container.AddFacility(new TypedFactoryFacility());
    container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));

    container.Register(Component.For<TopLevel>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IDependencyOwner>().ImplementedBy<DependencyOwner>();
    //there will be more IDependencyOwner Implementations in the future
    //No reason to register it anymore, it will never be instantiated by the container
    //container.Register(Component.For<ITransientItem>().ImplementedBy<TransientItem>()
        //.LifeStyle.Transient);

    //container.Register(Component.For<ITransientItemFactory>().AsFactory());
    container.Register(Component.For<ITransientItemFactory>()
        .ImplementedBy<FactoryImplementation>());

    TopLevel top = container.Resolve<TopLevel>();
```

Comment: I would put your topmost reference in a singleton which would control when it gets disposed.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja my understanding was that singleton was the default LifeStyle and that any component where you don't specify one was a singleton

Comment: If your Singleton implements IDisposable you have control of what happens at the point in time that all references to the Singleton are lost or the application ends.  If you are using the Form as the container, it's actually not a singleton (though it is probably instantiated once), but passed into the Application context where it may be disposed of early.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja I tried explicitly declaring it as a singleton and there was no change. The factory is still always disposed prior to the thing that depends on it.

Comment: Sounds like the only option is to use the `Dispose` method of the singleton to loop the contents of the factory and dispose them individually before disposing the factory.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja the issue here is that the factory is already disposed when `DependencyOwner.Dispose()` is called. This seems like a bug to me. The TypedFactory should not dispose before something that uses it as a dependency. Everything else, including a concrete implementation of that factory works this way. I am not sure why it would be intended for TypedFactories to work any differently.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug

Comment: No it's not a bug. This was definitively answered several days ago, however, the question and detailed answer have been deleted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322876/control-the-order-of-component-disposal

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt while related, this is not the same question. I realized that I was incorrect about the dispose order of dependencies in windsor as I did more testing, however, as far as I can tell typed factories are always disposed prior to things that depend on them. I decided it would be better to just start over, rather than basically rewrite the entire existing question.

Comment: Then it would have been better to update the previous question with your discovery so that others can benefit from what you learned.

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt I was on the fence about that. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve contributed a fix for this which shipped in Castle.Windsor 4.1.0!

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/pull/344
https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/releases/tag/v4.1.0